# Getting 403 when trying to send a file to AWS S3

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a simple app to test uploading files to ASW S3

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + filename;        
    client = new AmazonS3Client();
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest()
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = keyName,
        InputStream = new MemoryStream(ReadFile(path))
    };
    PutObjectResponse response2 = client.PutObject(request); 
}
```

and my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="AWSRegion" value="eu-west-1" />
    <add key="AWSProfileName" value="default"/>
    <add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="C:\aws_service_credentials\credentials_two.txt"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I am getting the error

```
The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (403 Forbidden)
```

When I run my app.

Weirdly It was working  up until recently.

I also have a aws console app, that shows you a wizard that allows you to enter your credentials `aws_access_key_id` and  `aws_secret_access_key`.

Weirdly also, this aws console app works fine when sending files and does not show the 403 error.

My packages file

```
<packages>
  <package id="AWSSDK.Core" version="3.1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AWSSDK.S3" version="3.1.5.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Could you double check that your credentials are exactly the same in both cases? It's very easy to mis-copy credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, make sure that there is a [default] section title in the credentials file:

`[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY`